# Count of NAs colwise by a group

Tags: r

I know that the following syntax in R will give me the count of NAs by variable. How do I stratify this by a grouping variable?

```
na_count <-sapply(x, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
```

Comment: looks like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477748/r-count-na-by-group) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786453/function-to-count-na-values-at-each-level-of-a-factor) question

Comment: What about a reproducible example?

Comment: Without grouping variable, it's much simpler to use `colSums(is.na(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~grp, data=dat, FUN= function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.)))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD,  function(x) sum(is.na(x))), grp]
```

---

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments, `rowsum` is another option where we can do the group by operation while summing.  We used `+` to coerce the logical matrix (`is.na(dat)`) to binary as the function will not work with logical class.

```
 rowsum(+(is.na(dat)), dat$grp)
```

Comment: had success with dplyr; not with aggregate, which I tried earlier as well with no success.

Comment: @user2340706 If you had showed a reproducible example, it would have been easier.

Comment: I would go with `rowsum(+(is.na(dat)), dat$grp)` in base R. But can't test it as OP couldn't be bothered to create a reproducible example. And btw, answering questions with zero effort just encourages help vampires.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I was also thinking about `rowsum` but couldn't test it.